# Can I access Application Helper methods in a RSpec request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

Given I have a `full_title` method in ApplicationHelper module, how can I access it in a RSpec request spec?

I have the following code now:

`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
    module ApplicationHelper

    # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
    def full_title(page_title)
      base_title = "My Site title"
      logger.debug "page_title: #{page_title}"
      if page_title.empty?
         base_title
      else
        "#{page_title} - #{base_title}"
      end
    end
```

`spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb`

```
   require 'spec_helper'

   describe "User Pages" do
      subject { page }

      describe "signup page" do 
          before { visit signup_path }

          it { should have_selector('h2', text: 'Sign up') } 
          it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign Up')) } 

      end
    end
```

On running this spec, I get this error message:

`NoMethodError:
       undefined method full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000003d43138>`

As per the tests in Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-user_pages_spec), I should be able to access the application helper methods in my user spec. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: I have the exact same code and it works for me.  Can you add more information to your error message?  Also, do you have a github repo you can share?

Comment: Have you created your `utilities.rb` file with the helper, in your `spec/support` directory?

Comment: I checked out [your code](https://github.com/movingahead/sample_app) and all specs passed.  Did you migrate your database and not restart spork?

Comment: Then see listing 5.26 in your book. That is how the author has the helper made available in rspec. Rspec will auto load files in `spec/support`.

Comment: @veritas1 Ok, I oversaw that listing. Thanks a lot. Can you add this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Sorry, I was running a different spec without the `full_title` helper which was executing. My bad. I had missed the `utlities.rb` file as @veritas1 pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the helper in `spec/support/utilities.rb` as per listing 5.26 of the book.

Comment: Presumably, it's in application_helper.rb because you want to use it in your application. Moving it into spec/ would prevent that, and copying it over isn't very DRY. Nultyi's is the better approach.

Comment: Yes it is, if there is a spec for the helper method.

Answer (score 40):

Another option is to include it directly in the spec_helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: at least for me, this only works in `rails_helper` since `ApplicationHelper` is not yet loaded when running `spec_helper` (rails 6.0.2)

Comment: In rails 5.1 it only worked when i added include ApplicationHelper directly in the file, not inside the RSpec configure block

Answer (score 10):

I am doing [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) (Rails 4.0 version) using currently-latest versions of each gem. I experienced a similar problem wondering how to include the ApplicationHelper to the specs. I got it working with following code:

## spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include ApplicationHelper
end
```

## spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "User pages", type: :feature do
  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do 
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { is_expected.to have_selector('h2', text: 'Sign up') } 
    it { is_expected.to have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign Up')) } 
  end
end
```

## Gemfile

```
...
# ruby 2.2.1
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.1' 
  ...
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
  ...
```